# PHP MySql - very slow data loading

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql data table with just 30 000 rows. It is not a big data table, but the loading time is significantly higher (more than 60 secs). I have 3 table called Category, Products and Companies. I need to loads Products and Companies data based on selected category. Here is my code. It works, but loads very slow..

```
"
SELECT p1.CompanyID
     , p1.NameE as ProductName
     , p1.CategoryID
     , c1.CompanyID as CompanyID
     , c1.NameE as CompanyName 
  FROM Products as p1 
  JOIN Companies as c1 
    ON p1.CategoryID = ".$row['CategoryID']." 
   AND p1.CompanyID = c1.CompanyID 
 GROUP 
    BY ProductName 
 ORDER 
    BY CompanyName ASC LIMIT 0, 15;
";
```

Comment: Please provide execution plan for the query

Comment: Why you are using group by without aggregation function ? .. (this could return unexpected  result for column not in group by and cause an error starting to mysql 5.7)

Comment: Move the p1.CategoryID=".$rpw['CategoryID']." from the ON clause of the join to a WHERE clause. It isn't part of the relationship of the join, and constrains the number of records in the primary table.

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require as a minimum SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the results of the EXPLAIN. As noted above, in the absence of any aggregating functions inclusion of a GROUP BY clause is liable to provide an erroneous result.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have indexes on the columns used in the ON clause of the join. Then try changing your query like this:

```
$queryList = $db->query(
    "SELECT p1.CompanyID, p1.NameE as ProductName, p1.CategoryID, c1.CompanyID as CompanyID, c1.NameE as CompanyName 
    FROM Products as p1 
    INNER JOIN Companies as c1 
    ON p1.CompanyID=c1.CompanyID 
    WHERE p1.CategoryID=".$row['CategoryID']." 
    GROUP BY ProductName 
    ORDER BY CompanyName ASC 
    LIMIT 0, 15");
```

Comment: Thank you Sloan for your suggestions, it improves the performance. But still it takes more than 30 secs to load the data (down from 60 secs). I have indexes on the columns.

Comment: What hardware/os are you using for the server? I did a test with 30k dummy records and three tables like you describe on a shared hosting server. It took less that 0.23 seconds to run the query. Other than hardware and related issues (defrag, etc.) the only thing I can think of is how the tables are defined. Are you using large field types? Check the Indexes to be sure they are defined. Check the execution plan to see if they are being used. Are your ID fields unsigned integers? Post your table definitions and maybe someone can spot something that may help.